# When is an invisibility cloak invisible?

Tags: harry-potter

When is an invisibility cloak invisible?

Obviously it is invisible when put on by a wizard, and visible when packed after laundry.

But is it visible or invisible when there's something other than a wizard inside? A cat, a chair, a pencil, a piece of dust?

Comment: Great, now I've lost the coat rack and the cloak!

Comment: whenever the plot requires it of course ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Invisibility Cloaks do not seem to become invisible if hung up on a clothing hook.

Kreacher takes Harry’s Invisibility Cloak and hangs it up on a hook near other clothes hung up similarly. The Cloak, or the hook it is hung on, are not said to turn invisible.

> “Shoes off, if you please, Master Harry, and hands washed before dinner,’ croaked Kreacher, seizing the Invisibility Cloak and slouching off to hang it on a hook on the wall, beside a number of old-fashioned robes that had been freshly laundered.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 12 (Magic is Might)*</sup></sub>

Presumably, if Kreacher hanging the Invisibility Cloak up made it and the hook it was hanging on invisible, that would be mentioned. Since it is not, it seems most likely that it would still appear to be a silvery cloak when hanging.

#### Invisibility cloaks will be invisible over a dead body.

An invisibility cloak will make a dead body it is used to cover invisible. Barty Crouch Jr. used one to cover his father’s body and left the body hidden under the Cloak in the Forbidden Forest until he could come back and dispose of it permanently.

> “You killed your father,’ Dumbledore said, in the same soft voice. ‘What did you do with the body?’
>
> ‘Carried it into the Forest. Covered it with the Invisibility Cloak. I had the map with me. I watched Potter run into the castle. He met Snape. Dumbledore joined them. I watched Potter bringing Dumbledore out of the castle. I walked back out of the Forest, doubled round behind them, went to meet them. I told Dumbledore Snape had told me where to come.
>
> ‘Dumbledore told me to go and look for my father. I went back to my father’s body. Watched the map. When everyone was gone, I Transfigured my father’s body. He became a bone … I buried it, while wearing the Invisibility Cloak, in the freshly dug earth in front of Hagrid’s cabin.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 35 (Veritaserum)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, an Invisibility Cloak will hide a dead body without needing a living wizard to be in any contact with it at the same time - it does not require a living person to “activate” its magic.

#### They will also be invisible over someone who does not want to be concealed.

Additionally, an Invisibility Cloak will turn a person covered by it regardless of whether or not they actually want to be invisible. Draco covered Harry with Harry’s own Invisibility Cloak, turning him invisible against his will, and left him hidden on the floor of the Hogwarts Express.

> “Malfoy dragged the Cloak out from under Harry’s immobilised body and threw it over him.
> ‘I don’t reckon they’ll find you till the train’s back in London,’ he said quietly. ‘See you around, Potter … or not.’
>
> And taking care to tread on Harry’s fingers, Malfoy left the compartment.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 7 (The Slug Club)*</sup></sub>

Harry did not want to be hidden on the floor of the Hogwarts Express, but his not wanting to be invisible then did not stop the Cloak from making him invisible.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's ever mentioned one way or the other, but could it be that invisibility cloaks have two sides, one invisible and one visible? That way, if you transport it, stow it or hang it on a hook you would turn the visible side out for the convenience of finding it again. But if you want to hide someone or something you turn the invisible side out. This would still be consistent with the three examples given here.

Comment: @Emil Out-of-universe this is how it was actually done in the movies: One side of the cloak had some (visible) texture, the other side was green so it could be made invisible in post-processing.  So when Harry puts it on in the movies, he is turning it inside-out.

Comment: Creates a bit of a funny in-universe image, @luator. "Harry throws his invisibility cloak over his head only to realize all he can see in the darkness is a faint bit of green. Realizing he's got it on inside-out, he quickly flips it around, just in time to be hidden before Filtch rounds the corner."

Comment: Unspecified: what happens if you take a dead body and turn it into a clothing stand, then hang an invisibility cloak on it?

Comment: @alfvaen The answer lies in the locked room of the Department of Mysteries